# C# 8 non nullable references and implicit usage

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In Resharper and Rider, there is the Jetbrains.Annotations attributes which can be applied to types and fields that are used implicitly.

e.g. if you define a data contract/DTO of some sort, you can decorate that with `[UsedImplicitly]` and Resharper will know to not flag this field as not used.

But, in C# 8. if you use the Nullable Ref Types feature.
Any non nullable field of such type will be flagged as "Never initialized" if you don't explicitly set those fields to non null values.

Is there some way to tell the C#8 compiler that "hey, ignore this, just trust me on this one" ?

e.g.
Assume we have a request message such as this, maybe it is passed to an ASP.NET endpoint or similar.

```
class LoginRequest
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
}
```

The compiler will complain that UserName is never initialized, which it isn't because it is initialized by a web client. e.g. a SPA app.

What is the correct way to suppress such warning?

Comment: This post would be clearer with a code example.

Comment: You can suppress warning as suggested by visual studio

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize it with a `null` value that is marked as being non-null:

```
public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
```

This seems strange at first but is a pretty straightforward way of declaring that something may technically be `null` for a short time, but is known not to be when actually used.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `#nullable disable` in the context.